# nginx uwsgi ingore the xxx in location/xxx

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

My code in `nginx.conf` as follow

```
location /shixi {
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
```

When I enter the url as `ip:port/shixi`, django told me no url `shixi` match, because the true url is `127.0.0.1:8888/shixi` and I want to ignore `shixi`, when I enter `ip:port/shixi`, it will be passed to `127.0.0.1:8888` instead.

Comment: you want to do a redirect?

Comment: except redirect, is there another way solve this?